# How does + work while adding character types? Adding character '1' and '2' gives me 99 or 'c'. Why is it not '3'?

Tags: java, operator-overloading

Some arithmetic operations I tried:

```
'2' - '1' = 1 (as expected)
'2' / '1' = 1 (makes sense)
'2' + '1' = 99 (how?)
'2' * '1' = 2450 (why???)
'2' % '1' = 1 (again why?)
```

Comment: A `char` is a number. See [this](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

Comment: I understand that. when you add numbers 1 and 2, shouldn't you get 3? Why is it 99 and not 3?

Comment: you add the ascii codes of the two characters. '1' = 49 and '2' = 50. to add you can add 1 to '1' to obtain 2. 49+50 = 99, 49*50=2450, 50%49 = 1, 50/49 = 1.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it now

Edit: Thanks for the explanation